# cannot pm2 list in docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I build a Docker image with Node.js and pm2. I started the container with:

```
docker run -d --name test -p 22 myImage
```

Then I go inside the container with:

```
docker exec -it test /bin/bash
```

In the container, exec the command:

```
pm2 list
```

And it stuck here:

[image]

P.s.: My application works well in the Docker container, if I add `CMD pm2 start app.js` in the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 6):

If your dockerfile CMD is a pm2 command, you have you include --no-daemon arg option so pm2 runs in the foreground and so your docker container continues to run.

An example Dockerfile CMD:

```
CMD ["pm2", "start", "app.js", "--no-daemon"]
```

Otherwise, without --no-daemon, pm2 launches as a background process and docker thinks the execution of the pm2 command is done running and stops.

See https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/259

Answer (score 2):

```
CMD ["pm2-docker", "pm2.yaml"]
```

This is the new approach.

Please do not use previous approaches.

Comment: Why is this the new way? Doesn't this just create a duplicate of the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: This is the right way using pm2 and docker. This way each single container runs one thread on every core and load balances between cores. Alternatively, you can just use docker only and have one container runnning on each core.